# how to read cin one by one in C++? element type is different

Tags: c++, cin

The user will input: string1 string2 123, and in my main, I hope to get my variables string str1, string str2, int num get the input data. So after the user input, str1 = string1, str2 = string2, num = 123. I will use cin to read the data, but how to read them one by one? Thank you!

Comment: I'm new to C++ so I don't understand the cin very much. I tried to use getline() but I don't know how to implement it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the strings have no spaces in them, you can simply extract them:

```
cin >> str1 >> str2 >> num;
```

Comment: Thank you! And what will happen if the user only input string1? (if I didn't do any exception check.)

Comment: @lkkeepmoving: Why don't you try it?